# Using ID for ordering when merging multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database

let's say I have two tables: blogs and comments. Each has title and created columns.

Now I want to create a table named activities that should track activity log of each member including blogs as well as comments. Columns would be simple: id, author id, title and link.

From now on, activities could be sorted by ID as any new comment or blog would be added at the time of creation. This would avoid indexing created timestamp column and use ID for ordering.

How would you create the initial state of the activities table?

I cannot simply go through the blogs table first and then comments because even older comments would be added after the newest blogs (created timestamp ok, ID not ok).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, 'blog', created FROM Blog
UNION ALL
SELECT id, 'comment', created FROM Comment)
ORDER BY created
```

Then you can insert the result of the above query.